# How to locate font files given the font family name?

Tags: fonts

I would like to automatically locate all the files of Roboto **and** Sawasdee font families installed in my system.
Given that they are located in different paths inside `/usr/share/fonts`.
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's `fc-list` for that, it lists the installed fonts. On 14.04, you can use

```
fc-list | egrep -i "roboto|sawasdee"
```

This doesn't seem to work on 12.04 though, use
 `fc-list -v | grep file | egrep "roboto|sawasdee"` instead.

You could also use the font-manager, install it using `sudo apt-get install font-manager`.

Comment: It will not print path. only list font .

Comment: It does on my 14.04...

Comment: May be. But on 12.04 it is not doing may be `fc-list -v | grep file | grep Sawasdee` a solution for 12.04 users.
`